# Is a tuple simply an ordered set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

Can a tuple contain elements such as objects, set or tuples themselves.
And in a Cartesian product of a set of tuples and some other set, shouldn't the resulting set contain tuples containing tuples? (From its definition: ${\displaystyle A\times B=\{(a,b)\mid a\in A\ {\mbox{ and }}\ b\in B\}}$; if $a$ or $b$ is a tuple)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. You may also find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3950443) question to be of interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A two component Cartesian product is definitely different from a multi-component one. But many authors do not honer the difference and assume everything to be flatten in a canonical way.

As an example, say you've got three presents for Christmas, call them A, B and C. They can be packed in various ways, A, B together, C separate, or, each separate, or, A with a package containing B, C.

Each way, all presents are there but *packed* in different ways.